# Webgl application running slowly on chrome, but not firefox

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, firefox, webgl

The application:
http://vipiao.pythonanywhere.com/procedural_generation/game/index.html

See the bottom of the screen for the controls. The framerate is displayed all to the bottom.
When running the application in chrome the application run at about 10-20 frames per second. The number of triangles are about 36000. On firefox the framerate is easily 60 fps. This makes me think I've made some sort of mistake that for some reason does not affect firefox, as the alternative would be firefox be superior at running webgl. Using the chrome debugger I see the bottleneck of the application is gpu usage by far. While the character is standing still in the application till the world stops loading, which happens after a few seconds, the only places where render calls are made is at:

procedural_generation/game/render_engine/render_engine.js line 63:

```
this.gl.clear(this.gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this.gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

procedural_generation/game/render_engine/planet.js line 1638:

```
this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.vertexBuffer);
```

procedural_generation/game/render_engine/planet.js line 1827 and onwards:

```
    this.shaderProgram.use();
    // // Data buffers.
    for (let i = 0; i < this.arrayBuffers.length; i++) {
        const a = this.arrayBuffers[i];
        this.gl.bindBuffer(this.gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, a.buffer);
        this.gl.vertexAttribPointer(a.location, a.size, a.type, false, a.stride, a.offset);
    }
    // Create transformation matrix.
    // // Rotation.
    let transMatr = orientation.toMatrix();
    // // Translation.
    transMatr = Mat4.multiplyMatrices(transMatr, Mat4.getTranslation(position));
    // // Send matrix.
    this.shaderProgram.setUniformMatrix('projection',projection);
    this.shaderProgram.setUniformMatrix('view',view);
    this.shaderProgram.setUniformMatrix('model',transMatr);
    // Send other uniforms.
    this.shaderProgram.setUniformVector('cameraWorldPosition',cameraPosition);
    this.shaderProgram.setUniformVector('lightDir',new Vec3(1,1,1));
    //this.shaderProgram.setUniformInteger('textureDim',this.textureDim);
    // Render.
    this.gl.bindFramebuffer(this.gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null); // Make it render to the canvas rather than to the frame buffer.
    this.gl.viewport(0.0, 0.0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLES, 0, this.numberOfTrianglesToRender*3);
```

All these calls are made only once per frame, with the exception of the buffer bindings inside the loop, which are called 3 times. The performance of these calls should by my understanding be quite innocent except for the drawArrays call. this.numberOfTrianglesToRender is about 36000 when the world is loaded, and each triangle takes 120 bytes. The vertex and fragment shaders are very basic and can be found at:
procedural_generation/game/render_engine/planet.js line 835 getVertexShaderCode()
and 
procedural_generation/game/render_engine/planet.js line 915 getFragmentShaderCode()

My question is, what is it I do wrong that makes the engine perform so badly on chrome but not on firefox. Also, an additional note is that on firefox the mouse controls become very stuttering, cannot figure out why that is either but that is not the main question.
procedural_generation/game/utilities/mouse_control.js

Comment: On what system are you testing this? Windoes/Linux/Mac? On my rather old desktop Windows 10, I get 56-60 frames consistently with latest Chrome.   Did you try to turn off extensions?  The  times I have had problems with Chrome running very slow, it has usually been because I changed some Chrome setting or flag for experimentation and then forgot about it. So it might also be worth it to reset all settings and flags to default.    (Unless you tested on several machines of-course)

Comment: Works fine in Chrome Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit) for me. Check if you have "hardware acceleration" enabled.